# Read binary using python while knowing format and dimension

Tags: python, struct, binary, unpack, endianness

I am trying to read a binary file (float32) containing one variable whose format is little endian.

This binary should give a 3d variable with dimensions (8, 480, 1440).
There is supposedly no header as it is given in another file.

After struggling a lot to read the binary and trying different solutions seen here, I was finally able to run my script. But the output wasn't as expected (wrong distribution of points), which makes me think something went wrong at some point although I don't know where.

Here is a minimal example of the code that run but did not give me the expected results:

```
filename=["CMORPH_3HLY_19980102"]
with open(filename[0], mode='rb') as file: 
        fileContent = file.read()

data=struct.unpack("f" * (len(fileContent) // 4), fileContent)

nvar  = 1                                    
ntim  = 8
nlat  = 480
mlon  = 1440
data_ok=np.array(data)

cmorph=data_ok.reshape((mlon,nlat,nvar*ntim)).transpose()
```

I guess the problem comes from what's inside the struct.unpack but, as I am not very familiar with binary format and binary files in general, I don't know how to solve this. 
Any help and/or explanation would be appreciated !

Comment: What is the data type? 32-bit ints?

Comment: I think it is floating points with 32 bytes. This is what is used in a matlab script that read the same data. Is there a way to be certain ? Documentation says each record contain a real*4 array of data.

Comment: Why not using ` np.fromfile(file[, dtype, count, sep])`  Construct an array from data in a text or binary file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to stovfl, I solved this. Here is the code that combines the `np.fromfile` and the `reshape`.

```
cmorph = np.fromfile(file,type=np.float32,count=nvar*ntim*nlat*mlon)).reshape((nvar*ntim,nlat,mlon))
```